# Query inside mbcxp_AgingVisit Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a report called Aging by Patient and the query that I have is calling the stored procedure `mbcxp_AgingVisit`. I need the query inside the stored procedure but can't seem to find it anywhere. I googled it and saw that others are working on reports with `mbcxp_AgingVisit` so I was wondering if someone has a copy of the stored procedure.

I hope I make sense and any response will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database where the stored procedure is installed -> Progammability -> Stored Procedures -> Modify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried looking for it but it's just not there.

Comment: Can you call the stored procedure in your database?

Comment: Yes (At least I think so) I'm not directly using that database. I have an ETL that gets all the tables that I need.
Further explanation:
There is a table called Report which contains the queries that the report uses. That is where I found out that it uses that SP.

Comment: There is also a possibility that the database we are using is just a back up of the actual database.

Comment: So you have no real access to the database using management studio?

Comment: Nope. It's a client database.

Comment: Did you ever find this? i dont have access to read the data inside the procedure but do have access to run queries.